# Restricting object key type with const

Tags: typescript

I am able to define an object key type from a union like:

```
type Action = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type UserStates = 'active' | 'deleted' | 'dishonoured';

type Permission = {
  [key in UserStates]: Action[];
};
```

However, I have a scenario where the options are const literals like:

```
const UserStates = ['active', 'deleted', 'dishonoured'] as const;
const Action = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;

type Permission = {
  [key: typeof UserStates[number]]: typeof Action[number][];
};
```

This results in:

```
error TS1337: An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.
```

How should I define the key signature if this scenario?

Working Example for union types:

```
type Action = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type UserStates = 'active' | 'deleted' | 'dishonoured';

type Permission = {
  [key in UserStates]: Action[];
};

export const PERMISSIONS: Permission = {
  active: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
  deleted: ['bar'],
  dishonoured: ['baz'],
};

const hasPermission = (userState: UserStates, action: Action): boolean =>
  PERMISSIONS[userState].some((x) => x === action);

console.info(hasPermission('active', 'foo'));
console.info(hasPermission('deleted', 'foo'));
```

Comment: why not do this? `type Permission = { [key in typeof UserStates[number]] ...`

Comment: If you do what @TobiasS. suggests everything works as you might expect. https://tsplay.dev/wjZgbw This is exactly what that error message is suggesting you do.

Comment: @TobiasS. thanks, I missed the `in` with `typeof`. make that an answer, and I can award the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
type Permission = {
  [key in typeof UserStates[number]]: typeof Action[number][];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A Record instead will work:

```
type Permission = Record<typeof UserStates[number], typeof Action[number][]>;
```

This results in the type:

```
type Permission = {
    active: ("foo" | "bar" | "baz")[];
    deleted: ("foo" | "bar" | "baz")[];
    dishonoured: ("foo" | "bar" | "baz")[];
}
```